# How would you describe the energy of solution formation involved in the dissolution of sodium chloride in vinegar?

Tags: solubility

I have found that the lattice energy of dissolving salt in water is 779 kJ/mol. While 774 kJ/mol is its hydration energy. Subtracting the two values gives a positive number therefore dissolving table salt in water is endothermic. I know that vinegar comprises of mostly water but how do you exactly explain the energy absorbed and released in the process if acetic acid is involved? Is there any constant that you know involving the dissolution of salt in acetic acid?

Our teacher wants us to include a discussion comparing water and vinegar in dissolving salt considering the enthalpy of solution but I am not quite sure what that means. I don't know if this question is too basic but I would really appreciate if I would get some answers. Thank you T.T

Comment: Vinegar is a solution 6% acetic acid in water. I doubt that the heat of dissolution of salt in vinegar is really different from what it is in water. Dissolving salt in vinegar is not like dissolving salt in pure acetic acid.